# How well does Azure SQL Data Warehouse scale?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I want to replace all my on-prem DW on SQL Server and use Azure SQL DW. My plan is to remove the spoke and hub model that I currently use for my on-prem SQL and basically have a large Azure SQL DW instance that scale with my client base (currently at ~1000). Would SQL DW scale or I need to retain my spoke and hub model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Azure SQL Data Warehoue](http://aka.ms/sqldw) is a great choice for removing your hub and spoke model. The service allows you to scale storage and compute independently to meet the compute and storage needs of your data warehouse. For example, you may have a large number of data sets that are infrequently accessed. SQL Data Warehouse allows you to have a small number of compute resources (to save costs) and using SQL Server features like table partitioning access only the data in the "hot" partitions efficiently - say the last 6 months.

The service offers the ability to adjust the compute power by moving a slider up or down - with the compute change happening in about 60 seconds (during the preview). This allows you to start small - say with a single spoke - and add over time making the migration to the cloud easy. As you need more power, you can simply add DWU/Compute resources by moving the slider to the right.

As the compute model scales, the number of query and loading concurrency slots increase offering you the ability to support larger numbers of customers. You can read more about [Elastic performance and scale with SQL Data Warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-performance-scale/) on [Azure.com](http://azure.com)